# Cordova install platforms/plugins from config.xml

Tags: git, cordova, version-control, config

In Cordova, it is possible to save platforms and plugins into the `config.xml` file, this way :

```
cordova platform add <platform> --save
cordova plugin add <plugin> --save
```

This is usefull for versioning in order to not commit all this generated files.

But... how can I install them back from `config.xml` ?

Something like : `cordova platform add --source=config.xml` ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Upd: Official docs on this topic: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/platform_plugin_versioning_ref/index.html

Here is some docs on this feature from [Tools Release: April 21, 2015](https://cordova.apache.org/news/2015/04/21/tools-release.html):

> When adding plugins or platforms, use the --save flag to add them to
> config.xml.
>
> Ex: **cordova platform add android --save.**
>
> Existing projects can use **cordova plugin save** and **cordova platform save** commands to save
> all previously installed plugins and platforms into your project's
> **config.xml**.
>
> Platforms and plugins will be autorestored when **cordova
> prepare**  is run. This allows developers to easily manage and share
> their dependenceis among different development enviroments and with
> their coworkers.

Comment: ```Cordova prepare```  was what I needed. Thanks !

Answer (score 10):

To install all plugins **from** the config.xml file you run:

`cordova prepare`

Check what plugins are loaded with:

`cordova plugin list`

Answer (score 1):

Apparently running a command like `cordova serve` will automatically add all missing platforms/plugins !

Answer (score 0):

Run the command in your dir of outside www folder

```
$ cordova platform add ios - for adding ios platform
$ cordova platform add android- for adding android platform
$ cordova platform add blackberry10
$ cordova platform add firefoxos
```